# "your device isn't compatible with this version"

Tags: android, google-play

I put an app in the play store and my friend, who is running 4.0.3 on two devices, got the following message when trying to install my app : "your device isn't compatible with this version".

One device allows it to install and the other doesn't. I allow for API 3-15 and both devices are 4.0.3.  What's the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.snotyak.basicfuelcalcpro"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.2.3" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".CalcApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MainTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".CalcActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PrefsActivity"
            android:label="@string/prefs_name" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CalcTabView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".HistoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".AnalysisActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the AndroidManifest.xml and the name device that your friend has. Take special not of any `use-feature` and `permission` tags you have in your manifest.

Comment: My friend has a Galaxy S2 (doesn't work) and it works on his Transformer Prime.

Comment: At this point it could be a restriction in the Android Market settings, you could have accidentally filtered out the device somehow. Look at my updated post for details. Also try looking at ADB while trying to install the apk for details. Use the command adb install Filename.apk to install it to the Galaxy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double check the `<uses-feature>` tag in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. It sounds like your application requires a feature that one of the devices doesn't support.

You should also check to see if you have the following declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

You want your application to work for devices running API 3 and above (not APIs 3 through 15). The code above will ensure that your application works with all devices above API 3. Note that you generally don't want to use the `android:maxSdkVersion` attribute (if you are currently using it).

Comment: Doubtful that this is the answer. It's a hardware filter that's probably causing the incompatibility.

Comment: Ahh, right... didn't see that both devices were running 4.0.3. In that case, I'd need more information to determine what exactly is wrong...

Comment: I don't have any <uses-feature> tags. I did get rid of my android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Comment: What is the name of the application on the Google Play store and what device are you trying to install the application on?

Comment: This wasn't the answer but it was the answer I found most helpful.

Comment: @snotyak so, what _was_ the answer?

Comment: @me-- This post is 7 years old, so I doubt it's still relevant, but check out my (seemingly unhelpful) answer down below.

Answer (score 13):

Being that the 2 devices are on the same version the logical explanation that is causing the incompatibility message is that the devices are different and the app is using a feature that one of them doesn't support. Look at your AndroidManifest.xml and pay close attention to `uses-feature` and `uses-permission` tags. The Google Play store will use these to filter out devices that are not compatible.

For example if you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera">` and one of the phone doesn't have a camera then it will be filtered out. Because the request for the permission implies that your app needs a camera to function properly. You can fix this by adding `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />` into your AndroidManifest.xml. Of course, you'll also need code to safeguard your app from attempting to access the camera when it's not available.

Look at this page for more information, [Google Play Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html#manifest-filters).

Google Play has a way to indicate what's causing the device to be filtered out. It's very terse but go to the bottom of the page under devices and select Show Devices and then filter for Galaxy to verify that it's excluding based on manifest.

[image: Google Play Filter]

Comment: I only have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and it's necessary for my app :/

Comment: That should be ok. Almost all devices have writable memory.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of

```
  <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Always things defined in Manifest, Google Playstore Filters out Your app to some devices.
Something like:

1. Declared specific Target Sdk Version.
2. Defined Camera permission(Will filter devices without Camera)
3. Uses Feature Camera.
4. SIM enabled device.
5. Device with Wifi.
6. Min sdk version.

So, You have to keep in mind that you have to reach maximum devices for your target, you have to Opt out some of the features and Permissions.

Hope this gives you idea about releasing App.

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue with one of my testers, if the tester is using an old android, you'll have to provide a web link for that user to accept testing invitation, he\she will have to open the link in a browser and accept the testing invitation.

You can get the link from google play console, go the testing track summary page, open testers tab, scroll down to "How testers join your test", here you'll find two links, one for android and one for web, copy the one for web and send it to those testers, after they accept the testing invitation they can access the app from the other link and there wont be an error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I removed these permissions from Manifest then it started working:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />
```

This is because these permissions already exist in the library which we added in the app level `build.gradle` file, so there is no need to define them explicitly in the main Manifest file.

Comment: In my case i checked google play device catalog, then found Reasons the device is unsupported
Doesn't support required feature: android.hardware.camera2, android.hardware.camera2.autofocus, android.hardware.camera2.full