# Your device isn't compatible with this version

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

I have uploaded one apk to google play store, in some of the devices i get this error "Your device isn't compatible with this version" and i don't get the reason y.
I have given this permissions to my app i don't catch what might b the problem.
So if anyone can help me.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<!--
     <permission
    android:name="com.abc.xyz.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
-->
<permission
    android:name="com.abc.xyz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.abc.xyz.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: please see the link I think same question first check in google after that if your not got anything then ask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670002/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version

Comment: have you check in which devices you got these error?? please check this two page it will help you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

Comment: your device will be filtered based on the uses-feature tag. So the device without camera, autofocus & OpenGL won't be able to install this app.

Comment: there is many possible answers so please filter first in which devices you ll get this issue... try to resolve them. then after ask question over here

Comment: I have one device acer a3-a11 in which it is giving me error

Comment: acer a3-a11 is tablet so have you used <supports-screens> in you manifest file?? if not then add it for 7,8,10 inch device(only if your app support that type of devices) like <supports-screens android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" /> i already give you two link (in above comment )first read that do changes as per your requirement.

Comment: hey thank you i have looked at links, i did not included supports-screens in my app so i ll include it but also two device one is moto e and another is samsung tab3 neo in which it shows same error

Comment: change this <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: Check you minimum and targeted sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is because of uses-feature tag in your manifest file.
devices not supporting these features are not compatible.

Just remove the uses-feature tag and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes defined in Manifest Filters out from Google Playstore to some devices.

1. Declared specific Target Sdk Version.
2. Defined Camera permission(Will filter devices without Camera)
3. Uses Feature Camera.
4. SIM enabled device.
5. Device with Wifi.

Before releasing your app you have to Opt out some of the features and Permissions and most of the time `Sdk version target`.

Hope these ideas are helpful for your app release.
Happy Coding.