# QuickBlox permission error

Tags: android, quickblox, motorola, quickblox-android

I have face a problem when I upload apk on play store and try to install that apk on Moto E. It says that ***"Your device is not compatible with this version"***.  is there any internal permission is Quickblox used internally, because before implement Quickblox  it installed on Moto E and work fine. library used by me of quickblox is following:

```
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:2.5.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.5.1@aar'
compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar'){ transitive = true}
```

and my application is used only simple chat not a video or audio functionality.

Comment: compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.5.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:2.5.1@aar'
compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.5.1@aar'
compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.5.1@aar'){
    transitive = true}

Comment: What is your min sdk version defined in gradle ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10670124/3111083 .It may help you.

Comment: I check all these things. and it would be fine my main motive is related to quickblox

Comment: your system hardware requirement is preventing it from installing.