# Getting "Your device isn't compatible with this version" on Galaxy S8

Tags: android, xml, ionic-framework

I recently released my app to an Alpha group on Google Play but I keep getting the error "Your device isn't compatible with this version" on my Galaxy S8.

This is an Ionic app so here is my config.xml (Some information ommitted):

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget id="---" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
        <name>---</name>
        <description>
            --- 
        </description>
        <author email="---" href="http://ionicframework.com">
            ---
        </author>
        <content src="index.html" />
        <access origin="*" />
        <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
        <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="orientation" value"portrait" />
        <hook type="after_prepare" src="package-hooks/android_custom_values.js" />
    </widget>

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml (Which I believe is generated): 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.moment2380651" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="false" xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android" />
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.ADMMessageHandler$Receiver" android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.ionicframework.moment2380651" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.ionicframework.moment2380651.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.ionicframework.moment2380651.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

My App does use the camera however, there doesn't seem to be a  tag in my AndroidManifest which I think is strange.  As far as I know the min and max version of the SDKs are correct (16-25).  What else could be the cause?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10670124/5202007

Answer (score 0):

remove  uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps
and support screens from AndroidManifest.xml and release it.

Comment: Whenever I try to remove uses-feature android.name="android.hardware.location.gps it comes back whenever I do a cordova build --release android.  Even if I just add the flag 'required=false' it will still add it - Then fail because I now have 2.  Is there a way to remove this permission from config.xml?