# Play Store: your device is not compatible with this version

Tags: android, google-play

When I publish my application, there is no problem on some phones and compatibility problems occur on some phones. I shared the manifest and gradle part below, I didn't understand what I did wrong. There is no problem in the Play develoepr device catalogue.

[image: Error Image]

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"  />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"
        tools:targetApi="tiramisu">



        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="androidx.appcompat.app.AppLocalesMetadataHolderService"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="autoStoreLocales"
                android:value="true" />
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9937060478156830~6086699458" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}



android {
    namespace 'com.word.lingo'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.word.lingo"
        minSdk 21
        //noinspection EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 21
        versionName "1.0.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        resourceConfigurations += ["en", "tr", "fr", "de","es","it"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }






    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures{

        viewBinding true
    }

    androidResources {
       // generateLocaleConfig true
    }
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'


    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti-compose:2.0.4'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti-xml:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.mmoamenn:LuckyWheel_Android:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.1'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:2.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:19.0.0"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    





}
```

What did you try and what were you expecting?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670002/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version

Comment: Or would targeting sdk 33 instead of 34 change this, did you upgrade that?

Comment: There is nothing I haven't tried in a week. I tried these too and it didn't work

Comment: Compile skd: 34  target sdk. : 33 As I said, it didn't work. I get an error when I change the compile sdk

Comment: In a separate question you could look at how to avoid an error changing the compile sdk. Also the key part from the linked question is highly upvoted and basically says this is expected behavior, "Look at your AndroidManifest.xml and pay close attention to uses-feature and uses-permission tags. The Google Play store will use these to filter out devices that are not compatible."